# Problemas con expresiones regulares en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de buscar los números dentro de un string, cuando lo hago solo me trae el último número de ese string.

```
var exp = string.match('\:\d*[0-9]\,');
```

Lo que trato de hacer es buscar los números que van despues del caracter : y antes de , pero no me sale bien

```
var string = 'Caja_cebolla X100 :1.5, Caja_tomate :2, Caja_cebollin :0.25'; // Busco que me tome los números que estan delante de : y antes de ,
var exp = string.match('\:\d*[0-9]\,');
console.log(exp);
```

Básicamente busco los números después de : y antes de ,. Ejemplo:

> En Caja_cebolla X100 que me tome el número 1.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. La expresión regular siguiente, busca que inicie con dos puntos
   **\:**, en seguida un digito **\d** que contenga o no un punto decimal **+(.\d{1,2})?** para finalizar busca todas las coincidencias con **/g**.
2. Usamos los dos puntos como ancla para que no choque con el X100, posteriormente eliminamos los dos puntos haciendo un mapeo del arreglo devuelto y remplazando por "vacío".
3. No se puede usar la coma al final, ya que no todos los valores tienen una.

Espero te funcione!

```js
var string = 'Caja_cebolla X100 :1.5, Caja_tomate :2, Caja_cebollin :0.25';
var exp = string.match(/\:\d+(\.\d{1,2})?/g).map(e => e.replace(':',''));
console.log(exp);
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta, tanto por el resultado como la explicación.